# How do I iterate through all wx.CheckBox instances?

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I have a wx frame where I have a quite a few checkboxes.  Ever so often when the user changes the settings in a drop down menu (wx.ComboBox) I'd like to clear all the checkboxes.  Currently, I've implemented a method that gets called when a change in the ComboBox happens and it clears each check box manually, i.e.:

```
def ClearCheckBoxes(self):
    self.cb_EnableControl.SetValue(0)
    self.cb_EnableRun.SetValue(0)
    self.cb_EnablePower.SetValue(0)
    ...
    ...
```

Although I only have about 10 of these, my ClearCheckBoxes method would be much cleaner if it were something like this:

```
def ClearCheckBoxes(self):
    for CheckBox in self.AllCheckBoxes:
        CheckBox.SetValue(0)
```

Also, I suppose I could create a list (i.e. `AllCheckBoxes`) and add all the checkboxes to the list as I create them, and then it would only be a matter of iterating through the list.  But the point here is that I'd like to know if there was an pre-defined way of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

```
for control in self.GetChildren():
    if isinstance(control, wx.CheckBox):
        control.SetValue(False)
```

Comment: Thanks @lacks.  I tried what you mentioned above but get the following error: `TypeError: 'WindowList' object is not callable` on the self.Children() call

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something super ugly like:

```
[checkbox.SetValue(0) for checkbox in dir(self) where type(checkbox) == type(wx.Checkbox)]
```